# Excel VBA - Trouble importing WhatsApp chat history files into an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, import, chat, whatsapp

Here is what a typical WhatsApp history chat file (.txt) looks like if opened in Notepad.

[image]

Note that there are 4 messages in the example, each starting with a date/time stamp & username.
Also, there're characters present that mark the end of every message (and seem to be Chr(10) to me).

What's more, the 3rd message (the to-buy list) consists of multiple lines, which in WhatsApp chat is achieved by hitting the Enter key.

My goal is to import the data above into an Excel sheet so as each of the four messages ends up in a row of its own, like below:

[image: Desired result.xls]

So far, I've been trying and failing miserably using the Workbook.OpenText method. The problem is that the multiple lines of the to-buy list end up in separate rows rather than being treated as a whole message.

I need a quick and elegant solution, too, as I'll need to process huge chat files with thousands of messages.
So, of course, I could loop through and merge lines based on whether they have  date/time/username stamps, but that takes a whole lot of time on a big file.

**EDIT:** Please, find below the code that I'm using at the moment to import the .txt files. I was not *demanding* an elegant solution, sorry if it came out like that. I just meant I would love for it to be elegant eventually, just need a clue or two, or more.

```
Sub ImportTXT ()

ChatFileNm = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), >*.txt", Title:="Select Chat File To Be Opened")

If ChatFileNm = False Then Exit Sub
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SourceSheet = FSO.GetBaseName(ChatFileNm)

Workbooks.OpenText filename:= _
        ChatFileNm, _
        Origin:=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlTextQualifierNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _ 
        Tab:=False,Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: David, thanks anyway. It's my first posting, if that matters. Yes, I have code I have trouble making work the way I want, see the edit above. And yes, I'd like some free code, and some free words of wisdom, but only to push me in the right direction. And I'd appreciate it if you could grant me some.

Comment: I would try reading the text using the `FileSystemObject`. Looks like you could parse based on the `23.05.16` format at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @hey thanks for editing to include your code -- I have a suggestion that I posted below. If your file is funky in terms of line breaks, we can add some additional logic to handle those.  Let's see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so since the OpenText method isn't working for you, let's start with something like this which uses the built-in I/O methods ([Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) and [Line Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264130.aspx)) for reading files, it should be faster than `FileSystemObject` and since you're dealing with the raw text/data, you will have more flexibility than just using the `Workbooks.OpenText`.

If your text file is mangled (as it seems to be in the screenshots you've provided) we may need to add some conditional logic to identify when each "line" starts, but to get started, let's see how this works.

It will begin writing each line in Column A, at Row 1 and then sequentially to rows 2+ for each successive line.

```
Option Explicit
Sub f()
Dim ChatFileNm
Dim FF As Long
Dim destination As Range
Dim ctr As Long
Dim ln$

ChatFileNm = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), >*.txt", Title:="Select Chat File To Be Opened")
If ChatFileNm = False Then Exit Sub
Set destination = Range("A1")
FF = FreeFile
Open ChatFileNm For Input As FF
Do Until EOF(FF)
    Line Input #FF, ln
    'Write the line in to the destination
    destination.Offset(ctr).Value = ln
    'Increment the counter
    ctr = ctr + 1
Loop
'Release the lock on the file
Close FF

End Sub
```

Alternatively, build the entire text string from the file, and use the `Split` function with `Chr(10)` as your delimiter:

```
Option Explicit
Sub f()
Dim ChatFileNm
Dim FF As Long
Dim destination As Range
Dim ln$, txt$

ChatFileNm = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), >*.txt", Title:="Select Chat File To Be Opened")
If ChatFileNm = False Then Exit Sub
Set destination = Range("A1")
FF = FreeFile
Open ChatFileNm For Input As FF
Do Until EOF(FF)
    Line Input #FF, ln
    'Write the line in to the destination
    txt = txt & ln
Loop
'Release the lock on the file
Close FF

'Write to the sheet:
Dim lines
lines = Split(txt, Chr(10))
Range("A1").Resize(Ubound(lines)+1).Value = Application.Transpose(lines)

End Sub
```

Comment: David, thanks for your input, but the code you suggested doesn't seem to do the job. I will edit my post above to include a screenshot of the resulting column.

Comment: Can you also edit your post to include *actual text input instead of screenshot*?